# What browser versions of Firefox support Bootstrap?

Tags: css, firefox, bootstrap-4

I'm doing some programming with `bootstrap` and was tasked with making sure it's compatible with `Firefox v42+`. According to [this](http://caniuse.com) it isn't supported by v42 of `Firefox`. I have no clue how correct this information is and just wanna double check and make sure it is correct. The documentation says `Firefox` is supported but not specific versions. Anything helps!

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/browsers-devices/#desktop-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific information about `Bootstrap 4` for `Firefox v42`. This [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/) to the official documentation tells:

> Bootstrap supports the latest, stable releases of all major browsers and platforms. On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 10-11 / Microsoft Edge.

It means that older versions are also supported. Assuming, that first [Bootstrap](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.1.0/docs/#about) was tested on `Firefox 4+`, I am pretty sure the latest version also supports older versions of `Firefox`.

To be 100% sure, I would suggest you to write to `Bootstrap` support. They have `Slack` channel.

EDIT:

I have found the information. This [link](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/browsers-devices/) tells:

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 1 major version",
  ">= 1%",
  "Chrome >= 45",
  "Firefox >= 38",
  "Edge >= 12",
  "Explorer >= 10",
  "iOS >= 9",
  "Safari >= 9",
  "Android >= 4.4",
  "Opera >= 30"
]
```

So you can use it with `Firefox 42`.

Comment: I have found a link too official docs, please have a look to my edited answer

Comment: Thank you, now I can assure my team that is supported and good to go!

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap v4 uses flexbox, and flexbox is supported by Firefox since v28 released in 2014.
Refer [Can I use flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

For know bugs on different browser, refer [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/browser-bugs/)

It is safe to say, that you can use bootstrap v4 in production